Showing that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
Here is the question I am thinking about:
Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra and its closed under countable increasing unions.Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
My thoughts:
I want to prove that it is closed under complements and countable unions. I was able to prove that it is closed under complements but I do not know how to prove that it is closed under countable unions. I believe I should creat a sequence of disjoint sets and then use continuity from above or below, I am not sure. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Isn't closure under complement part of the definition of an algebra? So not sure what you had to prove here. As for closure under countable unions - well, you know there is closure under finite unions, and also under countable increasing unions. Can you see how to turn a countable union into a union of countably many increasing sets? (forget about continuity, this is much easier)

Hint: $\cup_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n=\cup_{n=1}^{+\infty} (\cup_{i=1}^n A_i)$.

@Mark the answer for your last question no.

@Asigan can you clarify what you wrote please. I did not get it.

@Hope Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of elements of $\mathcal A$. We desire to prove $\cup_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n\in\mathcal A$, which is equivalent to $\cup_{n=1}^{+\infty} (\cup_{i=1}^n A_i)\in\mathcal A$. Can you use the hypothesis to conclude the latter?

@Asigan no still I do not see how, sorry

$\cup_{i=1}^n A_i\in\mathcal A$ by closedness under finite union; $\cup_{n=1}^{+\infty}(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i)\in\mathcal A$ by closedness under union of ascending sequence.
